# using prinf function for repeated patterns

Tags: scripts, awk

I have codes which append the patterns into text file w.r.t. the user's input as follows;

```
echo -n "WHICH STATIONS?"
read station
awk -v input="$station" '
 BEGIN {
        n = split(tolower(input), user)     
         pattern=  "force %-4s npos 0. .0001\n"       
    }
    {print}
    /<< write after this line >>/ {
        for (i=1; i<=n; i++)
             printf pattern, user[i]
        exit
    }
' ./data > data_2
```

let assume user's input `abcd ab12` then commands append below lines;

```
force abcd npos 0. .0001
force ab12 npos 0. .0001
```

I need to add `epos` and `upos` strings for each input for separate lines as follows (for same inputs as above example);

```
force abcd npos 0. .0001
force abcd epos 0. .0001
force abcd upos 0. .0001
force ab12 npos 0. .0001
force ab12 epos 0. .0001
force ab12 upos 0. .0001
```

How can I modify the `pattern` option to append these lines into the data file?

Comment: What is the input data from file `data`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I understood from the information given by you:

```
awk -v input="$station" '
BEGIN {
    n = split(tolower(input), user)     
     pattern=  "force %-4s npos 0. .0001\n"       
}
{print}
{
    for (i=1; i<=n; i++){
         print "force " user[i] " epos 0. .0001" 
         print "force " user[i] " upos 0. .0001" 
   }
}
' data
```

In `for` loop for each user `epos` and `upos` strings are getting printed as per your requirement.